# Get id of queried row in azure

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I've queried a row like this:

```
var email = emailEntry.Text;
var emailQuery = await MobileService.GetTable<Users>()
                                    .Where(item => item.Email == email)
                                    .ToEnumerableAsync();
```

I now need to find the id of the row that the email was found in. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a model like this

```
public class Users {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

You just need to access any models in the enumerable.

```
var email = emailEntry.Text;
var emailQuery = await MobileService.GetTable<Users>()
                                    .Where(item => item.Email == email)
                                    .ToEnumerableAsync();

var user = emailQuery.FirstOrDefault();
if(user != null) {
    var id = user.Id;
}
```